# Testing against the 'current_user' with Devise in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm just starting out with Ruby and Rails, trying out Devise with Rails 3. I've got a loop around a list of Posts, each of which has an associated user. I only want to display editing controls for those posts which are associated with the current user.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= link_to "show" %>
  <% if current_user = post.user %>
    <%= link_to "edit" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

(The above is simplified, and from memory, so I'm sure the syntax isn't entirely right - but you get the gist.)

If no user is logged in, the posts show as intended - there's a `Show` link, but no `Edit` link. However, if I am logged in at all, all of the `Edit` links show up, even fir posts created by a different user.

I've verified in the console that `User.find(1) != User.find(2)`, but for some reason the `current_user = post.user` evaluates to true no matter who is currently logged in. Is this to do with current_user being a helper as opposed to a "real" `user` object? How can I use `current_user` to get at the ACTUAL current user to make my comparison?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're assigning rather than testing - use == - i.e.

```
<% if current_user == post.user %>
```

Comment: I probably should've read my Ruby book more before skipping on to Rails. Not sure why I didn't instinctively use `==`, I'm a C# developer by day... Thanks!